# How to keep an activity work on background if I open another activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am using Google Voice in my android app, and I am connected the app to Bluetooth module, each time I call the Google Voice, the app try to connect to Bluetooth again, each time Google voice window Popped up, the connection lost, and once the window disappear, and the connection comes back again. So, Is there any way to keep them connected even I call the Google Voice window? Any ideas or help I will be appreciated. [image: picture of the Google voice app]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create background service for your problem. If you need persistent connection with your Bluetooth you can use intent service. If you are using android studio then it is very easy to create service. Just make sure you must have all necessary information about services and how to make then persistent in background.

Because of this your application will drain your device battery drastically. Make sure service is closed when application exit or all activities are finished.

See this link for more information
https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

Comment: OK I understand, what If I open the voice command as show above in the pict , the connection will stay between the Bluetooth module that I am using  and the app. if yes,another thing what If wanna keep the connection  between the device and the  Bluetooth module when I open another activity or app like the Phone calls, message.

Comment: As long as service is running your connection is persistent. If your did not stop service if your application is closed then also your connection is stable. Only if your Bluetooth module doesn't throw any exception at that time. So as long as service is running your connection remain.

Answer (score 1):

Place the Bluetooth related processing in a `Service`. Make the service foreground service.

Activity can connect/disconnect from service anytime.